# How Should I Upgrade native build app in android to Flutter build Android?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services

I have already built an android app in native android and now the same app I have built-in flutter. How should I upgrade the already built app in android native to newly built-in flutter in playstore?

I am facing the issue with the SHA 1 signature while uploading the app.

Please guide me through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sign your app with the same certificate you signed your native android app.
Have a look at: [Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)